# Winform mssql multi table update c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, sql-update

For MSSQL update in Winform, I want to multi update these table.

Would you give me the comment? it will be easy question..

```
 UPDATE PC SET PC.statusId = '3', Rental.RealReturnDate = '2018-11-12', Rental.Reason = ''
 FROM PC, Rental WHERE PC.rentalId = Rental.rentalId AND tagNo = 'EK18LT00002'
```

Comment: You can't update more that one table in a single statement

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE PC
SET PC.statusId = '3' 
FROM PC inner join Rental
on  PC.rentalId = Rental.rentalId
where tagNo = 'EK18LT00002' ;

UPDATE Rental
SET Rental.RealReturnDate = '2018-11-12', Rental.Reason = ''
FROM PC inner join Rental
on  PC.rentalId = Rental.rentalId
where tagNo = 'EK18LT00002';

COMMIT
```

Comment: Don't you have to use 2 UPDATE statements I don't think you can update 2 tables in a single SQL query.